# Obtain rectangle indicating 2D world space camera can see

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, xna-4.0, camera

I have a 2D tile based game in XNA, with a moveable camera that can scroll around and zoom.

I'm trying to obtain a rectangle which indicates the area, in world space, that my camera is looking at, so I can render anything this rectangle intersects with (currently, everything is rendered).

So, I'm drawing the world like this:

```
  _SpriteBatch.Begin(
                SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack,
                null,
                SamplerState.PointClamp,        // Don't smooth            
                null, null, null,
                _Camera.GetTransformation());
```

The `GetTransformation()` method on my Camera object does this:

```
    public Matrix GetTransformation()
    {
        _transform =
           Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-_pos.X, -_pos.Y, 0)) *
           Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *
           Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 1)) *
           Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(_viewportWidth * 0.5f,
               _viewportHeight * 0.5f, 0));
        return _transform;
    }
```

The camera properties in the method above should be self explanatory.

How can I get a rectangle indicating what the camera is looking at in world space?

Comment: Do you use rotation?

Comment: No, camera has fixed rotation.

Comment: You can just create one from the position of the rectangle then, viewport width and height, multiplied by scale.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that. Surely the camera position has to be involved?

Comment: Sorry, by position of rectangle I meant the camera... :)

Comment: Ah, that got me thinking. I've having to divide by zoom (something is back to front), but this seems to work: float CameraLeftBound = _Camera.Pos.X - ((Window.ClientBounds.Width / 2) / _Camera.Zoom );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's what seemed to do the trick:

```
 Rectangle CameraWorldRect = new Rectangle(
                Convert.ToInt32(_Camera.Pos.X - ((Window.ClientBounds.Width / 2) / _Camera.Zoom)),
                Convert.ToInt32(_Camera.Pos.Y - ((Window.ClientBounds.Height / 2) / _Camera.Zoom)),
                Convert.ToInt32(Window.ClientBounds.Width / _Camera.Zoom),
                Convert.ToInt32(Window.ClientBounds.Height / _Camera.Zoom));
```

Reduced CPU usage 3% by not drawing unnecessary tiles, happy days.

Comment: You could use your _viewportWidth(Height) instead of Window.ClientBounds.

Comment: Any particular advantage to one over the other?